# Tree traversal through 3d array

Tags: javascript, arrays, tree

Taking an input where yPerms is a 3d array of example:

```
[
    [[1,2,3],[4,5,6]],
    [[11,12,13],[14,15,16]]
]
```

The output has to be any possible combination of values in each row. For this example the correct output would be

```
[
    [[1,2,3],[11,12,13]],
    [[1,2,3],[14,15,16]],
    [[4,5,6],[11,12,13]],
    [[4,5,6],[14,15,16]]
]
```

The input in reality will have far more rows and columns so it can't be done with just a couple of for loops (at least I can't see how).

My attempt is a complete mess, the issue is that path within the for loop which is supposed to 'reset' temp, it seems to have taken value from within the next recursive function called:

```
    function treeTraverse(yPerms, unique, row) {
        var result = [];
        var path = unique||[];
        var n = row||0;
        if (yPerms.length <= n) {
            console.log("found a path");
            return path;
        }
        for(let m in yPerms[n]) {
            var temp = path;
            temp.push(yPerms[n][m]);
            result.push(treeTraverse(yPerms,temp,n+1));
        }
        return result;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was that unique and temp became the same variable in effect, just a pointer for each other, which isn't what I wanted, i wanted them to be separate but take on the same value so that I could manipulate temp without changing path. To solve this I simply used slice() on path so

```
var temp = path.slice();
```

which creates an identical duplicate of path and assigned it to temp.